# How to perform improved Euler integration for a 3D vertex model (network minimization)?

Tags: optimization, network

I am a PhD student who is struggling to implement a 3D vertex model. Vertex model  are commonly used by physicists in biology to understand how biological cells in a tissue coordinate together. In the model, the cells are represented by vertices and neighbouring cells are joined together through these vertices forming a network of polyhedra (shown below).

[image]

The vertices of the network can move in space according to the following model (please see equation 1). The problem that I have been facing is how to do numerical integration for moving the vertices in space. More specifically, how can I compute the gradient of potential energy (U) at a given vertex *i* in the network? The author has performed improved euler integration to evolve the network; how can this be done given these equations?

The value of eta is 1 and therefore can be ignored in equation 1.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks !

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, don't cross-post: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/32769/9667

Comment: reference: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l3mopnaupf71gj0/okuda2012%20-%20cell%20reconfig.pdf?dl=0